# Как узнать ip-адрес и браузер клиента на java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, vaadin

выслали ТЗ, в котором есть пункт: "также в базе данных сохраняются данные о IP пользователя и его браузере", как при помощи Vaadin или Spring вытянуть эту информацию?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vaadin+get+client+ip+address&oq=vaadin+get+user+ip&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.6713j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

```
@PostMapping(path = "/user", produces = "application/json")
    public void getUserSpy(HttpServletRequest request) {
     String userIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
     String br = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    }
```

Но все сильно зависит от реализации приложения. Если фронт идет через какой нибудь шаблонизатор, то это работает. Если есть отдельный фронт с  каким нибудь сервером, то скорее всего на проде работать не будет.

Comment: Front через vaadin)

Comment: А как получить браузер?

Comment: То есть это шаблонизатор, как я понимаю. Тогда должно работать.

Comment: Добавил вариант для браузера.